# Lock one axis of particle rotation

Tags: particles, axis

I'm using grass objects in a particle system to create a small field and need to animate it with the turbulence field. When applied the grass objects in the particle system sometimes rotates in the Z axis so it doesn't look right, how can I lock it to only rotate in the X and Y axis?